# Postgres ignores table constraints, scans all inherited tables even if constraints don't match

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, partitioning

I have a Postgres table from which about 1000 inherited tables have been created for partitioning data.

Each inherited table has a constraint on a timestamp column called `capture_time`

`capture_time>=X and capture_time<Y`

X and Y are different for each inherited table and form continuous, non overlapping ranges.

So when I run a query where I specify `capture_time between t1 and t2`, I expect Postgres to know which tables (partitions) won't contain the data being queried by looking at the table constraints. But the explain output tells me that Postgres is scanning all tables (partitions).

How do I get Postgres to scan only the relevant tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found it. I was using `current_date` - a non-constant parameter, in the `where` clause. Changing `current_date` to a literal value, fixed it.

> Constraint exclusion only works when the query's WHERE clause contains
>   constants. A parameterized query will not be optimized, since the
>   planner cannot know which partitions the parameter value might select
>   at run time. For the same reason, "stable" functions such as
>   CURRENT_DATE must be avoided.